# How to embed a Rules Link in a View in order to trigger a Rules link to run?

Tags: views, rules, debugging

What is the general process to embed a Rules Link in a View in order to trigger a Rules link to run?

I have used the [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module to create a Rules Link embedded in a View (it's a View that combines all the details of a User).

I want the Rules Link to trigger a Rule which (when the reading user clicks " More Content From Author") will trigger the Rule to show a list of their latest postings in a HTML format.The paths work alright, it just doesn't seem to trigger the Rules Link to run the View.

If I add say a generic link in the Rewrite Result link path (say http://www.google.com), it works fine and finds the target. But my Rules Link URL "More-Content-by-Author" throws a 404 even though the link is set correctly.

I've got most things working, checked all the Permissions and set the "Execute Rules Link" permission in the said View, but still get a 404 error.

I have not added any variables (do I need to?).

After 6 hours, and I'm stumped now. Any suggestions?

Note: All my other Rules links work fine.

[image: View Field Setting]
[image: Rules Setting]

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 modules that can trigger events based on the 'current URL being viewed' (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Rules URL Argument](https://drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument):

  > ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
  >
  > - check if a URL argument is present
  > - compare the value of and URL argument
  >
  > It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.
- [Path Rules](https://drupal.org/project/pathrules):

  > ... implements Rules conditions for checking the URL against a given string for triggering actions.

You can also use the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module to generate a custom link that can trigger a rule. But that requires the link to be clicked to access the page and there might be an issue that the user must be logged in.

Comment: Arh, Path Rules could be the answer I'm, looking for, I'll get back to you after I've had a play with it. Thanks for the tip @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think indeed that that is going to be what you were missing. Too bad there is no feature on Drupal.SE to organize some type of "bets" between users (a variation of bounties). Anyway, look forward to get your further feedback on it later on ...

Comment: @PaulB Just curious if you had a chance already to "play with it". And if so: what was the result of it?

Comment: I have had no joy with the above functionality, Drupal is becoming a bind for my projects. But I'll persevere whilst considering another framework.